# How to remove nodePort Kubernetes - Traefik ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

Following this tutorial:

```
https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/deploying-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster-b03a0672ae0c
```

I am able to access the site by visiting `www.domain.com:nodePort`

Is it possible to omit nodePort part? Could you provide example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to omit nodePort part?

Yes and No.

- Not directly. Kubernetes always exposes external services even LoadBalancer type of services on a node port.
- Yes. If you front it with a load balancer. Either your own that forwards port `80` and/or `443` to your NodePort or a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type of service which essentially sets up an external load balancer that forwards traffic to your NodePort.

> Could you provide an example?

The NodePort service to expose your ingress is basically the same, you just need to setup your own external load balancer. (i.e AWS ELB/ALB/NLB, GCP load balancer, Azure load balancer, F5, etc, etc)

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
  type: NodePort
```

The [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) type is just a change on the type of service:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
  type: LoadBalancer
```

In the case above, Kubernetes will automatically manage the [load balancer in the provider](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/).

Comment: What to do in case of custom VPS... Since I don't have Load Balancer out of the box like in cloud providers?

Comment: Setup your own proxy or load balancer outside Kubernetes.

Comment: Any example for this?

Comment: For example, https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/haproxy-load-balancer-ubuntu/

Comment: I saw that one but IPs are added staticly what happen if one node go down will that proxy continue call that node?

Comment: Not really. But you need to have some sort of health check that the proxy checks on your app

Answer (score 1):

Try deploying the below code. This is a simple whoami pod which can be deployed along traefik and can be accessed at http://localhost/whoami-app-api when deployed on the local machine. The dashboard is also available at http://localhost:8080/dashboard.

Deployment File:

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRoute
    plural: ingressroutes
    singular: ingressroute
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: middlewares.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: Middleware
    plural: middlewares
    singular: middleware
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRouteTCP
    plural: ingressroutetcps
    singular: ingressroutetcp
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressrouteudps.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRouteUDP
    plural: ingressrouteudps
    singular: ingressrouteudp
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: TLSOption
    plural: tlsoptions
    singular: tlsoption
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: tlsstores.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: TLSStore
    plural: tlsstores
    singular: tlsstore
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: traefikservices.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: TraefikService
    plural: traefikservices
    singular: traefikservice
  scope: Namespaced

---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - traefik.containo.us
    resources:
      - middlewares
      - ingressroutes
      - traefikservices
      - ingressroutetcps
      - ingressrouteudps
      - tlsoptions
      - tlsstores
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: traefik-ingress-controller
    namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app: traefik

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.1
          args:
            - --accesslog=true
            - --api
            - --api.insecure
            - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
            - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
            - --providers.kubernetescrd
            - --configfile=/config/traefik.toml
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: websecure
              containerPort: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      name: websecure
      targetPort: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
      targetPort: 8080
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: containous/whoami
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami

spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami-whoami
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: PathPrefix(`/whoami-app-api`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
```

Comment: I am running on VPS it is now panding for load balancer...